# objects filter on base of url request

Tags: django, django-views

I have two similar classes, query filter is county code DE or NL.

Is possible to make a objects filter on base of url name and keep only one class? For example, if i point my browser to

> 127.0.0.1:8000/germany

django will call to filter

> feed__country__name='DE'

and

> 127.0.0.1:8000/netherland

will use

> feed__country__name='NL'?

My URL:

```
 url(r'^netherland/$', NLFeedList.as_view(), name='nl'),
 url(r'^germany/$', DEFeedList.as_view(), name='de'),
```

VIEWS:

```
class NLFeedList(PaginationMixin, ListView):

    model = FeedItem
    template_name = 'nl_feed.html'
    context_object_name = 'feed_items'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        items = FeedItem.objects.filter(feed__country__name='NL')

        if self.kwargs.get('category', None):
            return items.category(self.kwargs.get('category'))


        return items

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NLFeedList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(country__name='NL')
        return context

class DEFeedList(PaginationMixin, ListView):

    model = FeedItem
    template_name = 'de_feed.html'
    context_object_name = 'feed_items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        items = FeedItem.objects.filter(feed__country__name='DE')

        if self.kwargs.get('category', None):
            return items.category(self.kwargs.get('category'))

        return items

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DEFeedList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(country__name='DE')
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^(?P<country>germany|netherland)/$', FeedList.as_view(), name='feedlist')
```

and the **view**:

```
class FeedList(PaginationMixin, ListView):

    model = FeedItem
    context_object_name = 'feed_items'

    match = {'germany':'DE','netherland':'NL'}

    def get_queryset(self):
        code = self.match[self.kwargs['country']]
        items = FeedItem.objects.filter(feed__country__name=code)
        self.template_name = '%s_feed.html' % code.lower()
        if self.kwargs.get('category', None):
            return items.category(self.kwargs.get('category'))


        return items

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FeedList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(country__name=self.match[self.kwargs['country']])
        return context
```

Also, perhaps you don't need two templates else only one, in this case just remove this line `self.template_name = '%s_feed.html' % code.lower()` and set the `template_name` accordingly.

Comment: I not experienced python/django programmer so this was a very helpful. Unfortunately I receive syntax error on
`code.lower()
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Probably I will use only one template.

Comment: I found what was wrong need to be
'self.template_name = '%s_feed.html' % code.lower()'
instead
'self.template_name = '%s_feed.html' %s code.lower()'

Comment: Hi @Robert. I've updated the answer, it was my fault, I just did a quick type and didn't test the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to

```
url(r'^(?P<country>netherland|germany)/$', NLFeedList.as_view(), name='nl'),
```

Then access this new `<country>` parameter in your view using

```
country = self.kwargs['country']
```

Then do the necessary `if country = '...':` code block in your view.

Comment: I see @trinchet already posted his answer while I was typing mine. His seems to be more complete that mine. Go with it.